# Windows Phone 8 VoipHttpIncomingCallTask vs Periodic Task /Resource Intensive Task

Tags: windows-phone-8, voip, background-process

I am just a beginner and I was playing the ChatterBox Example in Windows Phone 8. The question arise on my head is - what are the pros and cons of VoipHttpIncomingCallTask over Periodic Task/ Resource Intensive Task? is VoipHttpIncomingCallTask works real time?  What if I use VoipHttpIncomingCallTask receive raw  notification and build my apps on it and never call OnIncomingCallReceived. If OnIncomingCallReceived is not invoked then does the Windows phone runtime allocates any resources after VoipHttpIncomingCallTask?

Answer (score 0):

VoipHttpIncomingCallTask is invoked by a push notification rather than a periodic updates. That's the main advantage. Other than that it is a normal scheduledtask, nothing more, nothing less.